# java array index out of bound: Line 17: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 119 out of bounds for length 26

Tags: java, computer-science

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isAlienSorted(String[] words, String order) {
        int[] new_alphabet = new int[26];
        for(int i=0; i<order.length();i++){
            new_alphabet[order.charAt(i)-'a'] = i;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<words.length;j++){
                int min = Math.min(words[i].length(), words[j].length());
                    for(int k=0;k<min;k++){
                        char ichar = words[i].charAt(k);
                        char jchar = words[j].charAt(k);
                        if(new_alphabet[ichar-'a']<new_alphabet[jchar-'a']){
                            break;
                        }
                         if(new_alphabet[jchar-'a']<new_alphabet[ichar]-'a'){
                            return false;
                        }

                        else if(k==min-1&&words[i].length()>words[j].length()){
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

Hope some one can get me out. I've checked this code few times but still don't know where am I wrong.

java run time error:Line 17: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 119 out of bounds for length 26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<words.length;j++){
```

If `i` goes to the last index then `j` will be `i + 1`. So `j` will
try to index one past the limit.

So the outer loop should go to `words.length - 1`.

Corrected, it would be.

```
for(int i=0;i<words.length-1;i++) {
       for(int j=i+1;j<words.length;j++){
```

You also made this mistake

```
  if(new_alphabet[jchar-'a']<new_alphabet[ichar]-'a'){
                            return false;
                        }
```

It should be `[ichar - 'a']`

Comment: Thx for your reply sir but the error still out there.